# updating 1:n:m association in activerecord

Tags: activerecord, associations

```
class Wall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shelves
end

class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book
  belongs_to :wall
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shelf
end


CREATE TABLE `walls` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
CREATE TABLE `shelves` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `wall_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `books` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `shelf_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want to move a book from one shelf to another, so I write...

```
  book.shelf = new_shelf
```

but this doesn't taken care of all the associations automatically.
When I query the old shelf for books, it returns the book I supposedly moved to another shelf.

what am I missing?

Comment: Did you call save after doing `book.shelf = new_shelf`? You also have to call reload on the former shelf if it was pulled form the db before the update takes place.

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto I feel dumber now... yep I was missing the save/reload. Thanks! I guess I was expecting some sort of telepathy from ActiveRecord... wanna put it as an aswer to get some karma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call save after doing `book.shelf = new_shelf`

You also have to call reload on the former shelf if it was pulled from the db before the update takes place.